# npm -v FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, npm, memory, garbage-collection, heap-memory

Hope you all are safe and doing well in this pandemic. please take care.

**Question:**

`node -v` working fine.

but
`npm -v` Error: heap out of memory

I dont know what is wrong with my PC

Please help.

Error
[image]